# Is the address of a Smart Contract fixed?

Tags: solidity, transactions, contract-development, addresses

I would like to know if the `address` of the `smart contract` is fixed.

I want some privacy for my application, so I would like to change the `sending address` and `receiving address` each time the `smart contract` receives a `transaction`.

Is it possible ? Something like `Hierarchical Key Derivation` ?

Answer (score 5):

A contract's address is fixed, for the formula see
[How is the address of an Ethereum contract computed?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/760/how-is-the-address-of-an-ethereum-contract-computed)

There is currently no privacy on the blockchain, all transaction details are viewable by everyone.

Yes, HD wallets are possible and for a wiki of them see [What Hierarchical Deterministic (HD) wallets are available for Ethereum?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1094/what-hierarchical-deterministic-hd-wallets-are-available-for-ethereum)