# Storing Ether based digital assets in a paper wallet

Tags: ether, paper-wallets, augur

This morning I was looking for a paper wallet generator to move Augur out of an exchange, and I found a reddit post saying that as Augur is an ETH based token you can use an ETH address to store it.

How would that work though - what happens if i move both Augur and ETH to that address? Would they both be accessible afterwards? I know i probably shouldn't do that, but I am just curious how it would work at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A paper wallet is a way of storing [private keys](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/26452/what-is-the-difference-between-a-private-key-password-brain-wallet-and-recove) which give you control over an Ethereum account (which includes the ether associated with it and any tokens it has). Each account essentially includes a number associated with it (the ether balance) and every ERC20 smart token contract contains a mapping of addresses to token balance. The account balance can't normally be decreased without the private keys and, similarly, the token balance. You will need to store some ether in the associated account to interact with the Augur contract, anyway (such as to send tokens). Thus, not only would they both be accessible afterwards, you pretty much *must* have ether in the account (unless you plan to never use the Augur tokens).

I'm not really sure why you think you shouldn't have Augur and ETH in the same wallet aside from a worry of putting all your eggs in one basket. In that case, you can keep a bulk of your ether in one account and put the remainder in another paper wallet. But now you have to protect two wallets.

Comment: So i need to first transfer some Ether (that would be used to pay for txns) to the generated paper wallet, and only then transfer augur?

Comment: You can transfer the Augur tokens *to* the account without transferring any ether. However, before you do anything with the tokens in that account, you will need to deposit at least enough ether to pay for gas.