# DAO withdrawal without keystore

Tags: go-ethereum, the-dao, dao, thedao-refund

I have been reading [here](https://theethereum.wiki/w/index.php/The_DAO_Refunds) about the withdrawal process. A friend of mine has participated in DAO and he needs some help - a couple of days ago found that DAO has failed and wants to withdraw.

All he has is :

- the DAO password
- the DAO address, which verified from the above links is entitled to some refunds.

So my most important question here is - that he should need a keystore/private key to get those back into an ether wallet right? Where should he have that? Should he have downloaded them/kept a backup from DAO or are these something else? Without those is there any way for getting back his deposited ether?

Update : There is no private key in his laptop - used shapeshift to convert BTC to ETH, and then send the ETH to DAO from within the DAO website.

Any way he can do anything?

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing as a password for the DAO (unless I'm forgetting something). By "DAO address", I'm assuming you mean "account that is holding DAO tokens".

Your friend needs the decrypted private key associated with the account that holds DAO tokens. If all your friend did was buy the DAO tokens from an account holding ETH, then the account that holds the DAO tokens is that account.

Not sure how your friend intended on doing *anything* without the private key to the account that the BTC was shapeshifted to, though. That's a bit confusing; are you sure he doesn't have access to the ETH account?

Comment: that's what he says, he gave me sth that looks like a normal password for a website and not a private key and he is kind of technologically agnostic. I am assuming he needs the private key for the ETH account the BTC was converted to ( via shapeshift ).

Comment: If he was using myetherwallet (the only ethereum wallet I know of that doesn’t use a login system and uses passwords aside from geth and parity), that password is needed in addition to the encrypted key store. See also https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/26452/what-is-the-difference-between-a-private-key-password-brain-wallet-and-recove

Comment: from what he said - he got the address generated from daohub. never used etherwallet so does not have an idea of what a private key should be. password is the password to access daohub - that's all he has plus the address. I assume nothing he can do right?