# Do I have control over my account or not?

Tags: wallets

I am pretty new to this ethereum thing so here's my question:

I have created a wallet with a password. Afterwards I formatted the PC and installed an utility that mines through nanopool. My question is: Did I have to backup something else than just the wallet's number and the initial password?

Thanks!

Comment: See also https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/26452/what-is-the-difference-between-a-private-key-password-brain-wallet-and-recove

Comment: So if I have this UTC file, I can sell and buy Ether on my account? The password it contains inside is not that big, 64 characters or something. Thanks for the help btw.

Answer (score 1):

When you say "account number" do you mean something like  `0x0092e7b523bcf35d18a50ae437d36aa212002cf6` ?

And when you say "initial password" do you mean a password you came up with?

If so, you do not have control over the account.

To have control over an account, you need its private key. A private key is basically a very large number. Wallet applications will usually store it on your hard drive in the *keystore* files, encrypted with a password you came up with. If you lost the encrypted private key, the password is useless because there's nothing to decrypt anymore.

When creating an account, most wallets will tell you to write down a sequence of words, or to copy something. That is your backup.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR** yes, you need to backup your keystore file which is located somewhere like `C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\Ethereum\keystore` (on Windows) in case you were creating wallet locally *(and if you were using some web service for this you probably had to download this file somewhere)*

and have a name like this `UTC--{year}-{month}--{account}`.

Sometimes services give you your private key without encryption, you should be very careful with it and [store it in safe place](https://revocent.com/best-practices-for-securing-private-keys/).