# Is my address valid?

Tags: blockchain, wallets, addresses

I'm using Blockcypher's API (https://dev.blockcypher.com/eth/#generate-address-endpoint )to generate Ethereum addresses. One such address that has been generated is :-

```
Public Address (bb46f25f6b5199dda7829aa09bd59a798f844a6)
```

However, when I try to use services like myetherswallet(https://www.myetherwallet.com/#send-transaction) to send funds to this address, it says address is invalid. Is my address correct?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I check if an Ethereum address is valid?](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1374/how-can-i-check-if-an-ethereum-address-is-valid)

Comment: @NicolasMassart
I already checked. It says valid. However, when I try to send eth to this address, it says invalid address.

Comment: Have you tried to add the 0x prefix? Myetherwallet requires it as I can remember.

Comment: @NicolasMassart
No, I haven't. However, shouldn;t the addresses generated by Blockcypher have the 0x prefix attached to them ?

Comment: Not necessarily. 0x is only to indicate it's an hexa string. This is not part of the address.

Comment: More info about 0x: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/503/what-is-the-0x-i-see-around-ethereum-for-example-i-see-addresses-that-start-wit

Comment: Written in hex, an address is 40 characters long. `bb46f25f6b5199dda7829aa09bd59a798f844a6` is 39 characters long.